# Remove 50Hz noise from a system

Tags: analog, adc, mains, analog-filter

I am working on measurement circuitry and one of the challenges I have is the 50Hz noise. Is there some analogue circuitry that could be implemented to eliminate this?

I am using multiple LDOs to power everything on my board and there is a main LDO with Ultra High PSRR to receive power from the benchtop power supply and its output is powering the rest of the LDOs in the system.

Is there any analogue circuitry I could implement before or after the main LDO to minimise 50Hz noise to the whole system?

I have an ADC on board and I am trying to speed up the measurement time.

Thank You.

Comment: You'll need to show the circuit that is being interfered with and state what levels of interference are present and by how much you need to reduce them.

Comment: What makes you think that 50Hz noise is coming from hum on the power supply voltage? I'd be a bit less skeptical if you were talking about 100Hz noise.

Comment: It is likely that the 50Hz is not coming from power supply but it may be in the signal you are measuring. Do try another supply to prove that it's not the power supply, but other supplies such as switch mode supplies may have other issues or reasons why they "leak" 50Hz to output. Batteries don't have those issues and are isolated from mains.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi Andy, I haven't fully developed the schematics yet but the signal I am reading is a small DC signal, scaled up by the gain of an Instrumentational amplifier and therefore I am using a sigma-delta ADC to read it. I was told by engineers who worked on similar projects that 50Hz noise will definitely be an issue.
I have never been impacted by the 50Hz noise in any other projects I have worked with before so I wanted to ask if there is a filter or some technique that could be implemented to eliminate it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The supply could have an Y cap between mains and output, or the supply might require a grounded outlet for proper operation but connected to ungrounded outlet.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the suggestion. I never considered the impact the outlet could make.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The 50Hz noise is coming from the power outlet and to some extent would be eliminated the CMRR of the instrumentational amplifier. Since I have never worked on this type of stuff before, my question is if there is some sort of filtering that could be implemented at the start of the system that could further ensure that the 50Hz noise never gets seen by the rest of the components. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: _"I was told by engineers who worked on similar projects that 50Hz noise will definitely be an issue."_ And how did these engineers fix the issue on the other similar projects?

Comment: Many sigma delta ADCs have an option when programming their filter to put a notch at 50 Hz. That's OK, if your desired sample rate is lower than 50 Hz. Often, the notch will be at multiples of 10 Hz, so you get both sides of the Atlantic, 50 and 60 Hz, with the same filter settings.

Comment: @Justme Exactly, so the LDO would have negligible effect. OP needs to supply an approximate schematic, including the power source and ADC specifications. Also we need to know what the signal frequency band is and the target noise spectrum. It's very easy to remove mains-frequency noise from a 1MHz signal, not so easy if it's 0-100Hz bandwidth. If the noise isn't too large (so that it causes too much mixing or clipping) one could also just grab it all and digitally filter it out in post-processing, but it's always better to eliminate it at the source as much as possible before trying to filter.

Comment: @Velvel Oversampling but they were using SAR 1-2 MSPS ADCs and I am using Sigma Delta AD7175 which is 250kSPS.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for the feedback. I will update the post with more info